# Enum with NSnumber

Tags: objective-c, c, enums

How do I create an enum that contains NSNumber ??
i have a coredata persistence in my application, an entity has a status property declared as Integer 16 in coredata that means it is an NSNumber

I would love to be able to declare my enum in order to contain NSNumber and not int so i can use them without having to write this awful thing

```
enum {
  ERROR,
  INCOMPLETE,
  OK
} EventStatus;

[myObjectOnCoredata setStatus: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:INCOMPLETE]];
```

and just:

```
[muObjectOnCoredata setStatus: INCOMPLETE];
```

I think it shoul be possible since I can declare the enum as NSInteger, but it still is not good for me

thanks for any help

Comment: There's a huge difference between `NSNumber` and `NSInteger`.  `NSInteger` is just an integer type (typedef'd to `int` or `long`, depending on the system - `int` on iOS), while `NSNumber` is an object (`NSNumber *` being its pointer and how you use it), which means it must be created at runtime and therefore can't be a compile-time constant like `enum`s are.

Comment: `#define INCOMPLETE [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`

Comment: @holex `#define INCOMPLETE @1`. It's still an object and should be compared with `isEqual`

Comment: @Kevin, you are right, the obvious solution would be making proper getter and setter for the `status` property. to be honest, I would have downvoted this question (but I won't), because the question like "I'm too lazy to implement the setter or getter to achieve I want."

Comment: @holex i don't see why downvoting, actually I had not thought of making a getter and setter, hoping that i could declare an NSNumber enum seemed to me much more straight forward, now that i understand a bit more about those types I can make a deliberate choice, thanks

Comment: @MatteoToto, I would be seeing the reason clearly, because the `enum` works with `int` or `unsigned int` only. the `ANSI C` documentation defines it very well and the `Objective-C` is just a thin layer over the `ANSI C`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Name the status on the managedObject as `statusNumber`.

Then

```
@dynamic statusNumber


- (void)setStatus:(EventStatus)status {
    self.statusNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:status]];
}

- (EventStatus)status {
    return [self.statusNumber intValue];
}
```

Just hide the conversions into your implementation.

Comment: Because it's just an enum, not an typedef, the type have to be `enum EventStatus`

Comment: You can also check 'use primitive types' when exporting the `NSManagedObject` subclass in order to achieve this automatically for dynamic properties.

Answer (score 20):

Since last year WWDC you can use *boxed expressions* to create NSNumbers:

```
@(INCOMPLETE) // Equals to [NSNumber numberWithInt:INCOMPLETE]
```

See also here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html
At one point it says it's not available in any Apple compiler but now Clang is the default one which supports this since version 3.2

Or you add a method to your subclass of NSManagedObject taking an `enum EventStatus` which creates a number and calls the original method

Comment: It's even better to just create an setter and getter that internally converts an enum into the NSNumber. Just hide it into the object implementation.

Comment: sometimes, creating a proper setter and getter is much better code-pattern than this.

Comment: But this helps in other cases, where for example it's not in an object. For example, in our project I need to save enums in an NSArray, and [array addObject:@(ConstantValue)]; is very nice. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Enums cannot hold objects. Only integer types. 
You can box the value easily with @ or @() but take note of what kind of integer type it is so you inbox it correctly. 
It could be any of the signed or unsigned integer types. Failing to correctly unbox it may result in unexpected overflow due to implicit conversion with different length or sign. 
Although many enums use default implicit values starting from zero, that is not guaranteed.

So, check the enum definition and choose the right NSNumber method such as intValue for int.