# How to embed an Objective-C enum in NSNotification center?

Tags: objective-c, enums

I'm trying to post an NSNotification and I want to embed an enum in `UserInfo` so that I can manage the request.

**This is my code right now:**

```
ActiveMode requestedMode  = CommandMode;

NSDictionary *dict = @{@"requestedMode": requestedMode}:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:RequestModeChangeNotification
     object:self
     userInfo:NULL];
```

**And this is the error I'm getting:**

```
Collection element of type 'ActiveMode' (aka 'enum ActiveMode') 
is not an Objective-C object
```

**Originally—I understood this to be a C-Type error because my enum was declared as so:**

```
//typedef enum ActiveMode {
// CommandMode = 1
// } ActiveMode;
```

**But after I switched to using an NSInteger like so:**

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ActiveMode) {
     CommandMode = 1
 };
```

I'm still getting the same error—and a switch to NSNumber...like so...

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSNumber,ActionStatus) {
```

dosen't work.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: For now—I've solved it by initalizing an NSNumber from the int and including that in the dictionary as pert this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263081/enum-with-nsnumber

Comment: @Willeke — yes, this these questions are very similar and I basically used the same method as a solution :) — voted to close :)